# How to acess Servlet from Rest web service using Jersey

Tags: web-services, servlets, hashmap, jersey, data-sharing

I have a Webservice using jersey. I want to access a hashmap which is created in a servlet from rest service. That hashmap in servlet sholud be created only once during application startup.
this is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>GrpService_Map</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.ericsson.mapService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Service class TestSErvice is within com.ericsson.mapService package .My question is where will I place the required servlet that creates the hashmap and how will I access that map from TestSErvice ?
This is my service class TestService.java

```
@Path("/Service")
public class TestService {
    @GET
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/cacheserviceTestMap")
    public String createGroupCache(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException {

        //here i want to access the IndexMap hashmap
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

This is my servlet class

```
public class TestSerlvet extends HttpServlet{
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>> IndexMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,List<String>>>();
        Map<String,List<String>> signumMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
        List<String> grp = new ArrayList<String>();
        grp.add("1");
        grp.add("2");
        signumMap.put("eab", grp);
        signumMap.put("eabc",grp);
        signumMap.put("exy",grp);
        IndexMap.put("I", signumMap);
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post `TestService.java`, your servlet and the place in the service code that is failing or trying to access the servlet `HashMap`.

Comment: posted service class and servlet and from where I want to access the hashmap

Answer (score 0):

The servlet should be initialized (and mapped) in `web.xml` with `load-on-startup` set to a lower value than that of `jersey-servlet` in order for it to be loaded during container startup before any REST call can be serviced.  The servlet's `doGet` method's `IndexMap` local variable should be converted into a static field of the servlet which can be publicly accessed.  The initialization of that field should occur in the servlet's `init()` method in order to ensure that the `HashMap` is initialized before any REST endpoint can access it.

Once the above is done, `TestService.createGroupCache()` should be able to read the already initialized `HashMap` by calling the static getter method of the servlet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I am not getting the changes required in web.xml